Unable to compile upgrade parachain node after running `psvm v1.13.0`
I am trying to upgrade my parachain node from v1.12.0 to v1.13.0 using psvm but it does not compile successfully due to some mismatch conversion error of libp2p. I believe this PR must cause that issue but not sure how to fix it. https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/4198
error[E0277]: the trait bound `sc_network_types::PeerId: From<libp2p::PeerId>` is not satisfied
    --> /Users/chungquantin/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sc-network-0.41.0/src/service.rs:1593:51
     |
1593 |                 self.peer_store_handle.add_known_peer(peer_id.into());
     |                                                               ^^^^ the trait `From<libp2p::PeerId>` is not implemented for `sc_network_types::PeerId`, which is required by `libp2p::PeerId: Into<_>`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<libp2p_identity::peer_id::PeerId>>
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<litep2p::peer_id::PeerId>>
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<&libp2p_identity::peer_id::PeerId>>
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<&litep2p::peer_id::PeerId>>
     = note: required for `libp2p::PeerId` to implement `Into<sc_network_types::PeerId>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `sc_network_types::PeerId: From<libp2p::PeerId>` is not satisfied
    --> /Users/chungquantin/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sc-network-0.41.0/src/service.rs:1596:51
     |
1596 |                 self.peer_store_handle.add_known_peer(peer_id.into());
     |                                                               ^^^^ the trait `From<libp2p::PeerId>` is not implemented for `sc_network_types::PeerId`, which is required by `libp2p::PeerId: Into<_>`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<libp2p_identity::peer_id::PeerId>>
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<litep2p::peer_id::PeerId>>
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<&libp2p_identity::peer_id::PeerId>>
               <sc_network_types::PeerId as From<&litep2p::peer_id::PeerId>>
     = note: required for `libp2p::PeerId` to implement `Into<sc_network_types::PeerId>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `sc-network` (lib) due to 106 previous errors

Dependency mismatch error with sc-network-type
After trying to update the crate using command cargo update --precise v0.12.0, I got the another error with RPC crate.

Use of undeclared crate or module alloc
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `alloc`
      --> /Users/chungquantin/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/frame-benchmarking-35.0.0/src/v1.rs:1738:2
       |
  1738 | /     sp_runtime::format_runtime_string!(
  1739 | |         "\n* Pallet: {}\n\
  1740 | |         * Benchmark: {}\n\
  1741 | |         * Components: {:?}\n\
  ...    |
  1750 | |         error_message,
  1751 | |     )
       | |_____^ use of undeclared crate or module `alloc`


I encountered a similar problem when updating from 1.6 to 1.13. After analyzing the cargo.lock file and using the cargo tree command to help me, I isolated the problematic dependencies and resolved the issue by forcing specific versions instead of using the latest version using the --precise flag(^1) provided by cargo. E.g.
cargo update sc-network-types --precise 0.12.0


Thank you for fast response, after running the command, I ended up getting the another error: the trait From<RpcModule<_>> is implemented for Methods
Is this something you got as well? (Updated the post with attachment)

You probably have to align few other dependencies:

cargo update polkadot-node-core-pvf-common --precise 14.0.0
cargo update mmr-rpc --precise 35.0.0
cargo update sc-rpc-server  --precise 16.0.1
cargo update sc-network-types --precise 0.12.0


Thank you Leonardo, it works perfectly now. You saved me 10 hours debugging.

Hi Leonardo, another issue I got is "Use of undeclared crate or module alloc
" which I already added more information above. Do you know how can I solve that error?

I would suggest using Zepter (https://github.com/ggwpez/zepter) to verify that all the features are propagated correctly.

It does not work. I don't think the deps feature have anything to do with it.
